# Why is it relevant to call $Z_2^0$ term of Zernike polynomial "Defocus term"?

Tags: optics

### In what exact sense does $Z_2^0$ of Zernike polynomial represent the effect of defocus in optics?

$Z_2^0$ term of Zernike polynomial is call "Defocus term" in optics.

$Z_2^0(r,\theta) = \sqrt{3} \left(2 r^2-1\right)$

When I simply think about the effect of defocus in terms of wavefront, I think, however, its effect would be the deviation between two spherical wavefronts with slightly different radiuses, $R$ and $R+\Delta$. $\Delta$ is the deviation of focal length when defocus. I sketched a rough graph below:
[image: defocus in wavefronts]

In this graph, I think the effect of defocus is the deviation between the blue and the red spherical wavefronts, namely $\delta$. If we take a polar r axis from the center of the lense, the deviation$\delta$ can be written as

$\delta(r) = \sqrt{(R + \Delta)^2-r^2} -\sqrt{R^2-r^2} -\Delta$ .

**This is not identical to $Z_2^0$ obviously.**

---

If we Taylor expand $\delta(r)$ around $r=0$, we get:
$\delta(r) = \frac{1}{2} r^2 \left(\frac{1}{R}-\frac{1}{\Delta +R}\right)+\frac{1}{8} r^4 \left(\frac{1}{R^3}-\frac{1}{(\Delta +R)^3}\right)+\frac{1}{16} r^6 \left(\frac{1}{R^5}-\frac{1}{(\Delta +R)^5}\right)+O\left(r^7\right)$

Indeed, $\delta$ includes a $r^2$ term but it also contains more higher power series. If r is relatively small, $\delta \simeq Z_2^0$ but otherwise not. In this sense, it sounds not a general and analytic statement that $Z_2^0$ is "Defocus term".

---

My question: 
How is it justified to recognize $Z_2^0$ as the effect of defocus?

Comment: You can really simplify that Taylor expansion. Also note that the higher orders are also small when $\Delta<<R$, which is usually the case for normal aberrations. The answer might just be that this $\Delta<<R$ approximation and the paraxial approximation make it close enough to spherical defocus that no one cares.

Comment: @aquirdturtle I simplified the Taylor expansion and understood the behavior that the higher orders almost vanish when $\Delta \ll R$. If the statement "$Z_0^2$ is defocus" is based on the $\Delta \ll R$ approximation and the paraxial approximation, I understood. Therefore the statement holds when the two approximations are postulated, which is the usual case. Still other comments and answers are welcome.